# neo4j-shell-tools export-graphml does not work with -t Switch and cypher-query

Tags: neo4j

I try to use export-graphml from neo4j-shell-tools (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-export) to export a Subgraph to a graphml-file to use it forward wirh Gephi.

But when you use export-graphml with t-Switch (for gephi-optimzed export) combined with an cypher-query i get an error-message:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export-graphml -o /home/neo4j/out.graphml -t MATCH (n)-
[r1:GENANNT_IN]->(m)<-[r2:GENANNT_IN]-(z) WHERE n.id="26677" RETURN n,m,z,r1,r2       
SyntaxException: Invalid input '(': expected (line 1,    column 1) 
"(n)-[r1:GENANNT_IN]->(m)<-[r2:GENANNT_IN]-(z) WHERE n.id="26677" RETURN n,m,z,r1,r2"
```

Withou the t-switch export works:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export-graphml -o /home/neo4j/out.graphml MATCH (n)-
[r1:GENANNT_IN]->(m)<-[r2:GENANNT_IN]-(z) WHERE n.id="26677" RETURN n,m,z,r1,r2
Wrote to GraphML-file /home/neo4j/out.graphml 0. 100%: nodes = 236 rels =
668 properties = 547 time 2105 ms total 2105 ms
```

Any help would be nice.
Greetings,

Andreas Kuczera

Answer (score 2):

it works if you put the -t before the -o switch.

```
export-graphml -t -o /home/neo4j/out.graphml \
   MATCH (n)-[r1:GENANNT_IN]->(m)<-[r2:GENANNT_IN]-(z) \
   WHERE n.id="26677" RETURN n,m,z,r1,r2
```